# Cordova backgroundMode plugin doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I used Cordova backgroundMode plugin. And I have misunderstanding of it.

```js
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function ()
    {
             // Android customization 
 
             cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.setDefaults({ text: 'Doing heavy tasks.' });
             
             // Enable background mode
             cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.enable();
             
             if (cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.isEnabled()) {
                 console.log("Your value is : " + cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.isEnabled());
             }
             else { alert("its not enabled"); }

 
             // Called when background mode has been activated
             cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.onactivate = function ()
             {
                 console.log("its in bk mode");
                 setTimeout(function ()
                 {
                     // Modify the currently displayed notification
                     cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.configure({
                         text: 'Running in background for more than 5s now.'

                     }); 

                 }, 5000);
             }             
 
         }, false);
```

`onactivate` function should works when the app goes to the background mode, right?

I used Visual Studio 2015/Ripple to fire pause mode, which means the app now in background mode. So I should get a message in the console but I don't.

This a screenshot of the ripple and the console:
[image]
Thank you

Comment: This plugin (like most) will not work in the Ripple emulator: it consists of both Javascript and native code, so when you run Ripple in the browser only the JS part of the plugin is executed - the native part is missing.

Comment: Try adding counter and then run it in actual device then again check if what counter value is after some time of putting it in background mode if counter continuous working then your plugin is working fine. Its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and success on ionic 3 application.

While using the setTimeout the code will execute only one time. if you want to run your code multiple time either use setInterval or looping function.

In the normal case, the promise object won't work, or even the location services, use below code helps to work.

```
cordova.plugins.backgroundMode.disableWebViewOptimizations();
```